# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK no effect on widget

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget from which I can start two activities:

```
public final void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // some stuff here
    ...

    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), B.class);
    // forces intent update in pending intent
    intent.setAction("NO CACHE: " + System.currentTimeMillis());            
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rlFrame, pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), A.class);
    // forces intent update in pending intent
    intent.setAction("NO CACHE: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWidgetIcon, pendingIntent);

    // some stuff here

}
```

Scenario A:

- Starting Activity A from widget
- Press HOME button
- Starting Activity B from widget

Result:

Both activities are in the same task with Activity A as root.

Scenario B:

- Starting Activity B from widget
- Press HOME button
- Starting Activity A from widget

Result:

Both activities are in the same task with Activity B as root.

It seems as if the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is totally ignored. I expect that both activities are launched in separate tasks. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the answer to this?? I have been trying to figure this out probably for about a year now

Answer (score 1):

Use the following flag

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
```

Comment: Hmmm, have seen this before. But the note "Do not use this flag unless you are implementing your own top-level application launcher." made me think of not using it.

Comment: It will only work if there is no task launched in this app. Once a task is created it will use the same task to launch new activities

Comment: Seems to work when setting android:taskAffinity="my.custom.task" and starting the new activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Here's the output: 

Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{40a83b40 #133 A de.myapp.android.alternative.task}
    Run #2: HistoryRecord{40a83840 de.myapp.android/.widget.activities.WidgetActivity}
  TaskRecord{407adca0 #2 A com.sec.android.app.twlauncher}
    Run #1: HistoryRecord{40790120 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/.Launcher}
  TaskRecord{409a8cb0 #132 A de.myapp.android}
    Run #0: HistoryRecord{409a8a60 de.myapp.android/.MyApp}

Comment: BTW: The singleTask description tells us the following: "The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it."

Answer (score 0):

[Here says:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

> if the intent passed to startActivity() contains the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag, the system looks for a different task to house the new activity. Often, it's a new task. However, it doesn't have to be. If there's already an existing task with the same affinity as the new activity, the activity is launched into that task. If not, it begins a new task.

Use singletask maybe solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [PendingIntent documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.

This means that in order for it to know that it has a new `PendingIntent`, at least one of the things it is looking at has to be different. Yours has different `Intent`s, but the same `Intent` action. The easiest thing to change would probably be the requestCode (see bold).

> // some stuff here
>   ...
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), B.class);
>   // forces intent update in pending intent intent.setAction("NO CACHE:
>   " + System.currentTimeMillis());
>   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); PendingIntent
>   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, **0**, intent, 0);
>   views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rlFrame, pendingIntent);
>
> intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), A.class); //
>   forces intent update in pending intent intent.setAction("NO CACHE: " +
>   System.currentTimeMillis());
>   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); pendingIntent =
>   PendingIntent.getActivity(context, **1**, intent, 0);
>   views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWidgetIcon, pendingIntent);
>
> // some stuff here

Also, in my application, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is set as the flags argument in `getActivity()`. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation that I had:

I set my activity to android:launchMode="singleTop" and then override method onNewIntent(Intent) in the activity to handle the new intent coming from the widget.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)